# How to properly bold the decoded data in PHP

Tags: php

I am posting data to database which requires that I encode it. To this effect I used `htmlentities()` and to decode it am using `html_entity_decode()`

Here is my issue: My problem is that the decoded result is does not bold the "Helloworld" rather it shows back the Helloworld surrounded by the HTML bold tags.

```
$str = "<b>Hello world</b>";

echo $en = htmlentities(htmlentities($str));

echo "<br>decode<br>";

echo  $result = html_entity_decode($en);
```

Comment: Why are you applying `htmlentities` twice on the second line ?

Comment: Just `htmlentities($str)` should work

Comment: If u did not apply it twice htmlentities will not work. may be its a bug with XAMPP or some PHP version. Apply it twice works for me and using the latest version of XAMPP

Comment: Why do you think you need to encode it before storing in the database? You should only use `htmlentities()` when displaying on a web page and you don't want HTML in the data to be interpreted by the browser.

Comment: Databases don't interpret HTML, so you should be able to store it as given.

Comment: @Bamar, the Database am sending it is not just mysql. its Quickbase. If I did not encode the data, the API end point will discard the post. it is what they suggested i should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're encoding twice, you have to decode twice as well.

```
echo html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode($en));
```